# Paypal plus iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, paypal, integration

I'm using a simple Paypal Plus Integration iframe, as described:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({"approvalUrl": 'myApprovalUrl',"placeholder": "ppplus","mode": "live"});

</script>
```

But what I get as response from Paypal iframe, is:
[This iframe without input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqk7u.png)

What I really want is am ifram such as:

[This iframe with all credit card input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC8le.png)

Someone who had already integrate with Paypal Plus can give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js'></script>` instead of `<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Also, you will need to inform aditional parameters to PAYPAL.apps.PPP, like payerFirstName and payerLastName.

Once you import the "correct" script, you can inspect through Google Chrome, for instance, and you will be able to check the errors at the console tab.